# datatables striping uneven when filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

was wondering if anyone knew how to get around the following issue.  When I sort out a table that hides rows, the odd and even striping is off. Is there something I should be doing when it draws the table initially? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Here's the datatables code

```
if (!orderHistoryDTO) {
      orderHistoryDTO = $orderHistoryTable.DataTable({
        destroy:true,
        data:normalizedData,
        columns:orderHistoryMap,
        autoWidth:false,
        order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
        paging:false,
        dom:'ft',
        language:{
          search:'',
          searchPlaceholder:ax.L(5008),
          emptyTable: ax.L(903),
          zeroRecords: ax.L(903)
        },
        //"lengthMenu": [[1, 25, 50, "All"]],
        rowCallback:function(row, data, index) {
          $(row).addClass('order-event');
          if (!data.orderItemID) {
            $(row).addClass('order-only-event');
          }
        },
        drawCallback:function() {
          var api = this.api();
          filterOrderHistoryTable(api, $orderHistoryFilterSelector.find('.current a'));
        }
      });
    } else {
      orderHistoryDTO.clear();
      orderHistoryDTO.rows.add(normalizedData);
      orderHistoryDTO.draw();
      filterOrderHistoryTable(orderHistoryDTO, $orderHistoryFilterSelector.find('.current a'));
  }

//and the function that sorts 
   function filterOrderHistoryTable(dtO, $filter) {
   var filter = $filter.attr('data-filter');

   $orderHistoryTable.find('tbody tr').hide();
   $orderHistoryTable.find('tbody tr.' + filter).show();

   // item column
   var itemColumn = dtO.column(2);
   if (filter === 'order-only-event') {
    itemColumn.visible(false);
   } else {
    itemColumn.visible(true);
   }
  }


//CSS (background on tr:nth-child(even) set to white as default)
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
```

This is the screenshot of the markup and the page where certain rows are hidden
 [image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [column().search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) API? You could have a hidden column (visible: false) with the event classes (or some other identifier), then invoke the search programmatically on the hidden column.

Comment: Makes sense - I didn't write this code actually - more trying to fix someone else's. I'll take a look at that though